# Can I forward in jsp with parameters via button?

Tags: jsp, button, forward

I am working on a project and I want to forward from one jsp page to another via a button but there are parameters (email and password). That's why I can't use the href attribute. 
Can I use the forward inside the button tag? And if so, how?

Answer (score 0):

You can send parapaters to another JSP page in this way

```
//    This is the caller JSP page.
    <jsp:include page="Callee.jsp">
        <jsp:param name="param1" value="value1"/>
        <jsp:param name="param2" value="value2"/>
    </jsp:include>



<body>

  //    This is the called JSP page.

    param1: <%= request.getParameter("param1") %>
    param2: <%= request.getParameter("param2") %>

</body>
```

Comment: but I want the forward procedure to be done inside a button. Is this possible?

Comment: yes, of course... using post method for example

`<form method="post" action="mypage.jsp">  
...  
   <input type="text" name="param1">`